# Как осуществляется FULLTEXT-индексирование?

Tags: mysql, sql

Привет.

Как осуществляется FULLTEXT-индексирование? Я не о том, какими командами, а о том, как можно представить сам процесс их создания. Например, берется столбец с данными типа TEXT, склеиваются все данные столбца, убираются все короткие слова (по умолчанию коротким считается слово, которое меньше четырех символов), убирает шумовые слова (и, для, около...) и индексирует (по алфавиту выстраивает). Не знаю, правильно ли я написал, скорее всего нет.

Answer (score 2):

Оказалось, что я написал правильно. На другом форуме человек скинул картинку, по которой все понятно становится. Весь процесс индексирования можно понять по этой картинке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, берется столбец (в данном примере он называется Documents, у него могут быть данные типа `TEXT` или `VARCHAR`), все данные-строки сбрасываются в одну кучу, из этой кучи выкидываются короткие слова (по умолчанию коротким считается слово, если в нем 3 и меньше букв, это можно настроить), слова типа "для", "за", "у", "а"... тоже выкидываются, то, что осталось сортируется по алфавиту и запихивается в таблицу с индексами и ставятся ссылки на основную таблицу.

Answer (score 1):

Кое-что по сабжу рассказано, например, вот тут: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html
Думаю, для начального понимания будет достаточно.

Если очень коротко - то текст делится на токены (слова), они чистятся от стоп-слов и коротких слов, инвертируются, и уже в таком виде ищутся по предварительно индексированному содержимому таблиц(ы), также в инверсном виде

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/126014)

Comment: Ок, "самое главное" перемещено в ответ.